# Simple way to remove duplicate whitespaces and remove all \n efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

I have a file called `test.txt` It has a bunch of duplicate spaces. The `test.txt` file contains HTML. I want to remove all the unnessary whitespace to reduce the size of contents in the `test.txt` file. How can I remove the duplicate spaces and make the entire string on one line.

test.txt

```
 <center>
    <b class="test" >My       name

is


fred</      b> <center>
```

---

What I want to print

```
<center><b class="test">My name is fred</b><center>
```

What gets printed

```
<center><b class="test" >Mynameisfred</b> <center>
```

---

program.py

```
def is_white_space(before, curr, after):

    # remove duplicate spaces
    if (curr == " " and (before == " " or after == " ")):
        return True

    # Remove all \n
    elif (curr == "\n"):
        return True

    return False


f = open('test.txt', 'r')
contents = f.read()
f.close()

new = "";
i = 0
while (i < len(contents)):

    if (i != 0 and
        i != (len(contents) - 1) and
        not is_white_space(contents[i - 1], contents[i], contents[i + 1])):
        new += contents[i]

    i += 1

print(new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will leave a space between digits or letters.

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits


def main():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        parts = f.read().split()

    keep_separated = set(ascii_letters) | set(digits)

    for i in range(len(parts) - 1):
        if parts[i][-1] in keep_separated and parts[i + 1][0] in keep_separated:
            parts[i] = parts[i] + " "

    print(''.join(parts))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```